# AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'save' - Flask - WTForms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

So I'm trying to make a form to upload profile image but I keep getting this error `AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'save'` when I try to upload a image.

**My view:**

```
change_info_form = ChangeInformationForm()
    if change_info_form.validate_on_submit():
        if change_info_form.img.data != None:
            path = str(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']) + str(current_user.profile_img)
            if os.path.exists(path) and str(current_user.profile_img) != 'default.svg':
                os.remove(path)
            change_info_form.img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], str(current_user.id)))
```

**My form:**

```
class ChangeInformationForm(FlaskForm):
    img = FileField()
```

**My HTML:**

```
<img id="img-image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/{}'.format(current_user.profile_img)) }}" style="width: 2.5em; height: 2.5em;border-radius: 50%; margin-right: 1em;" />
                      <label for="img_input" class="img-input-lable">Select file</label>
                      {{ change_info_form.img(class='input-ctl-img', id='img_input', type='file') }}
```

**What I've tried:**

```
change_info_form.img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], str(current_user.id)))
change_info_form.img.file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], str(current_user.id)))
change_info_form.img.data.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], str(current_user.id)))
```

I searched everywhere but I can't manage to understand the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change_info_form.img.file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], str(current_user.id)))... use this one... and try to open it in incognito browser or clear the cache... looks light a cache problem.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha it gives this error: `AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'file'`